# confusion over datagrid erasing entries and general datagrid access

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid which I am using LINQ to fill, I then add some custom columns and fill them in programmatically - if the users clicks on the column header to re-sort, all the data in the added columns disappears.  I am obviously missing something very basic here but can't seem to see the forest for the trees.

I also have a couple of other questions about how I am doing things:

1. in my code I am accessing the datagrid custom cells by name, but the cells from the LINQ I have to use a cell reference number (i.e.: (1,2) instead of (total,2) (I realize that the name is replaced by a int) - can I name the columns?  How about if the end user re-orders them?

This is one of the first times I have used a datagrid like this so any pointers would be nice.

LINQ code to pull data

```
  Dim query = From m In db.details _
               Where m.InboundDate >= CType(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart, DateTime) _
               And m.InboundDate <= CType(MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd, DateTime).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59) _
               And m.ClientNo = 1 _
               Join md In db.Manifests On md.ManifestID Equals m.MainID _
               Select m.Zone, m.MainID, m.InboundDate, m.Zip, md.LadingPkgQty, m.Weight
```

code to fill with data and add columns

```
billingDatagrid.DataSource = query

billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("Package Rate", "Package Rate")
billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("LTL", "LTL Rate")
billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("Freight", "Freight")
billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("Fuel Surcharge", "Fuel Surcharge")
billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("Linehaul", "Linehaul")
billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("Billed Amount", "Billed")
```

Code example of how I am accessing the datagrid columns:

```
Select Case currentZone
    Case 1
        packageRate = Val(billingDatagrid(4, currentrow).Value) * zone1PkgRate
        billingDatagrid("Package Rate", currentrow).Value = packageRate

        If Val(billingDatagrid(5, currentrow).Value) > 500 Then
            LTLCharge = zone1_ltlBase + (Val(billingDatagrid(5, currentrow).Value) - 500) * zone1_ltlOver
        Else
            LTLCharge = zone1_ltlBase
        End If

        billingDatagrid("LTL", currentrow).Value = LTLCharge
```

At the end of all this I am going to have to create a .csv file for export - it is obviously important that the correst data stay with each row!

Thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class that has all the columns that you want in the grid and in the linq query select statement create a new instance of the class for each row.

Example:

```
Public Class GridData
    Public Zone as (type here)
    ...all your other columns from the query
    Public PackageRate as (type here)
    ...all your other columns you add programatically
End Class
```

Then in the query you can do:

```
Select New GridData with {.Zone=m.Zone, .MainID=m.MainID, .InboundDate=m.InboundDate, .Zip=m.Zip, .LadingPkgQty=md.LadingPkgQty, .Weight=m.Weight, .PackageRate=Nothing, etc }
```

With that you just assign the query to the datasource like you are doing and all columns should show up and still be there upon resort.  Hope it helps.  I think that could solve both your problems since the column names should also be all set, but i didn't test that part.

Edit:
You can assign the value for PackageRate in a loop even before you assign it to the grid datasource.

```
For each row in query
   'you can read and write any of the properties of the GridData Class as row.Client, etc here
Next
```

Then assign it to the datagrid

Comment: Thanks for the nudge! - for the code to work properly it does need properties etc... I have posted the complete working code in my previous post for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

OK - This is the final answer - the code work and the data stays where it should --

Thanks for the help!

My Class:

```
Public Class GridData

Private _clientno
Private _manifest
Private _packagerate

Public Property PackageRate() As Double
    Get
        Return _packagerate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _packagerate = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property manifest() As String
    Get
        Return _manifest
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _manifest = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property client() As Int16
    Get
        Return _clientno
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Int16)
        _clientno = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

The linq:

```
     Dim query = From m In db.details _
            Where m.InboundDate >= CType(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart, DateTime) _
            And m.InboundDate <= CType(MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd, DateTime).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59) _
            And m.ClientNo = 1 _
              Join md In db.Manifests On md.ManifestID Equals m.MainID _
            Select New GridData With {.PackageRate = Nothing, .manifest = m.MainID, .client = m.ClientNo}

   'No No -- billingDatagrid.Columns.Add("PackageRate", "PackageRate")
```

and a little code to fill in the packagerate with the value from the client number:

```
   billingDatagrid.DataSource = query
    Dim currentrow As Int16 = 0
    For Each r In billingDatagrid.Rows
        billingDatagrid("PackageRate", currentrow).Value = billingDatagrid("client", currentrow).Value
        currentrow += 1
    Next
```

The above code now works...

Thanks.

Comment: Solved:
add another property for the generated columns as well in the classes.
remove the code that creates the column
It now sorts correctly

Noet: the above code is correct - I removed the errors...